# Memory Usage Spikes When Scrolling (React Native FlatList)

Tags: react-native, optimization, scroll, react-native-flatlist

For some reason, when utilizing FlatList in React Native, my iOS simulator is beginning to chug when scrolling through the list, showing in increase in about 20% CPU usage when scrolling.  This is causing issues on slower devices, both Android and iOS (but especially Android).

I have tried a few optimization tricks with not much change.  I've added a shouldComponentUpdate function that returns false for each component in the list.  I have removed any calls to functions that are passed as props within render(), and I switch to using a FlatList in the first place (previously it was just a .map of an array that rendered components).

the render() of my component that utilizes FlatList

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          data={this.props.items}
          numColumns={2}
          windowSize={3}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (<ItemListRow
            goToItemOverride={this.goToItemOverride}
            item={item}
            navigator={this.props.navigator}
            category={this.props.category}
          />)}
        />
      </View>
```

the renderItem component's render()

```
    <Card
        style={this.styles.itemCard}
      >
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: 275 }} onPress={() => this.goToItemDetails(this.props.item)}>
              {this.state.loading ? <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }} >{this.defaultImage()}</View> : null }
              {this.image(this.styles.categoryimg, this.props.item.image.src)}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>
          <View style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18 }} numberOfLines={3}>{this.props.item.title}</Text>
            {
              (this.props.item.compare_at_price) ?
                <View style={{ height: 20, alignItems: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                  <Text style={this.styles.itemPrice}>
                    ${this.props.item.price}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={this.styles.strikethrough}>
                    ${this.props.item.compare_at_price}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                :
                <Text style={this.styles.itemPrice}>${this.props.item.price}</Text>
            }
          </View>
        </View>
      </Card>
```

I feel like this is a pretty simple list all things considered, so I'm not sure where the slowdown could be occurring.  I tried this with removing images from the list elements (thinking maybe the images could be too large) but there was no appreciable difference.  The max number of items in this list is around 30 so it's not like I'm trying to render an entire store's worth of items here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with the performance of `FlatList`. I tried every fix I could find, but eventually I gave up and switched to using [`recyclerlistview`](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview). It is more complex to use and requires a static height for each item, but it's worth it for the performance gain.

If you aren't using `Expo`, you could also try [`react-native-largelist`](https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist).

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the dimensions of your images, a 500kb size image with 3000x3000 dimensions would cause a lot of slow up due to the resizing process